# Add image to PHP email template

Tags: php, image, hyperlink

If I add the following line into the template the checkout becomes unavailable.

```
"\n<img src="https://example.com/images/girocode.png" alt="GiroCode" />" .
```

How can I make the work in PHP?

Comment: Cause you need to either escape or change the double quote.

Comment: You mean for the URL and for alt, right?

Comment: Yes you either change to single quote or escape with backslash.

Comment: Read more about escaping certain characters inside strings https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

you should use `\` before `"`

```
"\n<img src=\"https://example.com/images/girocode.png\" alt=\"GiroCode\" />"
```

Comment: He uses double quote for string and then uses double quote inside string for attributes. He either needs to escape the attributes or change either the string start and end position from single to double or change the attributes

Comment: I approve the edit tho.

Comment: @outoforder - If the answer helped you solve your issue, make sure you accept it (and upvote it for good measure).

Comment: It works perfectly! I tried to upvote but I'm not allowed to because of my newbie status.